# Simulating data for a Gompertz curve

Tags: r

I have a set of data that I have collected which consists of a time series, where each y-value is found by taking the mean of 30 samples of grape cluster weight.

The growth follows a Gompertz curve with formula `y = a*exp(-exp(-(x-x0)/b))`, with

- a = 88.8
- b = 11.7
- x0 = 15.1.

The data:

```
x = c(0, 28, 36, 42, 50, 58, 63, 71, 79, 85, 92, 99, 106, 112)
y = c(0, 15, 35, 55, 62, 74, 80, 96, 127, 120, 146, 160, 177, 165).
```

- x refers to the days from fruit set (i.e. 0 is when the time series starts)
- x values correspond to the days in which the measurements are taken (which depends on certain growth stages of grapes)

I want to simulate more data from this, with the same number of x and y values, so that I can carry out some Bayesian analysis to find the posterior distribution of the data.

Effectively what I need is:

- to simulate data which follows the Gompertz curve to create the posterior distribution. This data would technically be for "previous years" time series data.
- to construct and test the fit of the predictive time-series model based on the distribution

If there is some skeleton code where it is possible to change around the parameters, then this could potentially be very helpful for me too.

Thanks

Comment: I'd made some edits to the question to make it less confusing. Please have a read through and make the appropriate edits if I misread your original question.

Comment: @AdamQuek Just added a tiny bit, but otherwise that is what I am looking for

Comment: "simulate data which follows the Gompertz curve" is far too underspecified for a real answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's inspect your data

```
x <- c(0, 28, 36, 42, 50, 58, 63, 71, 79, 85, 92, 99, 106, 112)
y <- c(0, 15, 35, 55, 62, 74, 80, 96, 127, 120, 146, 160, 177, 165)
```

and fitted Gompertz curve

```
gFun <- function(x){
 a <- 88.8
 b <- 11.7
 x0 <- 15.1
 est <- a*exp(-exp(-(x-x0)/b))
  return(est)
}
```

by visualisation:

```
library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(ggData, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_function(fun=gFun, colour="blue") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

This doesn't look as a good fit. However, simulating data y|x at fixed x as in the vector above can be done by adding error term. I've used normal distribution with sd=4 for illustration.

```
nSim <- 10

simData <- data.frame(x=c(0, rep(x[-1], each=nSim)) ) # x[-1] removes 0 from simulation
simData$y <- gFun(simData$x) + rnorm(n=nrow(simData), sd=4)

ggplot(simData, aes(x=x, y=y) ) +
 geom_point(alpha=0.4) + 
 stat_function(fun=gFun, colour="blue") + 
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, max(x)) ) +
 theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for that. I will now have a think about how I can best use this to create the posterior distributions, and use this to compare with the original data.